# Correct way to use GetTable().OrderBy() in LINQ to SQL

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql

I'm new to LINQ and am trying to bind a Linq to SQL table to several controls (treeview, textbox, etc). I want to be able to make changes to textbox fields and save those updates back to the database easily.

I'm able to get the data from the database using:

```
    Private LinqDB As New DataContext(My.Settings.dbConnection)
    Property tblManufacturers As Table(Of dbManufacturers) _
        = LinqDB.GetTable(Of dbManufacturers)()
```

And binding the stuff to the controls was pretty simple. The TreeView fills with all the ManufacturerNames, and when I click on one it fills the TextBoxes for editing.
The problem is that the results aren't in the order I want in the treeview.
I was hoping something like:

```
    Property tblManufacturers As Table(Of dbManufacturers) _
        = LinqDB.GetTable(Of dbManufacturers)().OrderBy("ManufacturerName")
```

would work, but alas no.

I know I can use something like

```
Dim ManufacturerQuery = From ManufacturerName In tblManufacturers Order By ManufacturerName
```

But pushing changes back to the database seems more difficult.

**EDIT:** So, apparently I need to stop being cowardly and just try stuff...

```
Namespace Controls
    Public Class ManufacturerWarranty

        Private LinqDB As New DataContext(My.Settings.dbConnection)
        Property tblManufacturers As Table(Of dbManufacturers) = LinqDB.GetTable(Of dbManufacturers)()
        Property ManufacturerQuery = From m In tblManufacturers Order By m.ManufacturerName

        Public Sub New()
            InitializeComponent()
        End Sub

        Private Sub ManufacturerWarranty_Loaded(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
            Me.DataContext = Me
        End Sub

        Private Sub TreeView1_MouseDoubleClick(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs) Handles TreeView1.MouseDoubleClick
            StackPanel1.DataContext = e.OriginalSource.DataContext
        End Sub


        Private Sub cmdSave_Click(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles cmdSave.Click
            LinqDB.SubmitChanges()
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

And then I just bind my TreeView to ManufacturerQuery instead of tblManufacturers. My Save button still works for submitting changes, even when they are made to ManufacturerQuery instead of tblManufacturers.

Comment: When you say, doesn't work, do you mean, doesn't compile, fails at runtime or doesn't return results in the expected order?

Comment: Doesn't compile. Just typing that in gets me an error starting with "Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'OrderBy' can be called with these arguments"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, perhaps you want

```
Dim tblManufacturers As Table(Of dbManufacturers) _
    = LinqDB.GetTable(Of dbManufacturers)() _
        .OrderBy(Function(m) m.ManufacturerName)
```

---

So, to commit you'd do

```
Using linqDB As New DataContext(My.Settings.dbConnection)
    Dim tblManufacturers As Table(Of dbManufacturers) _
        = linqDB.GetTable(Of dbManufacturers)()

    -- change tblManufacturers.

    linqDB.SaveChanges()
End Using
```

What I wouldn't do is keep the context open while the user is interacting with the GUI. Likewise I (probably) wouldn't order the data unless I was displaying it to the user.

Comment: Closer. I get "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1[Data_Update.dbManufacturers]' to type 'System.Data.Linq.Table`1[Data_Update.dbManufacturers]'."

Comment: @AndyD273, where do you get that exception, are you having the problem you've shown or some newer problem with updating?

Comment: "How to commit changes to a table" is a different to the question, "How do I call `OrderBy`", no?

Comment: Yes. That is correct. Can you suggest a relatively simple way to commit changes when using the normal "Dim ManufacturerQuery = From ManufacturerName In tblManufacturers Order By ManufacturerName" pattern? Up to now I've mostly used winforms and ADODB. I'm pretty new to both WPF and Linq To SQL. Databinding and such is still confusing as I slowly wrap my brain around it.

Comment: Ok, followed your advice and made changes above. How do I close and reopen the context as needed for committing changes?

Comment: The context is automatically disposed (and closed) when the code leaves the `Using` block. The context can be reopened in same way, and it makes sense to use a `Using` block every time, so your code can't leak connections. What you need to consider is, how will I know whats been changed, from any `Events`, or even better `Commands` that you configure.